# Emacs Python parenthesis indent

Tags: emacs, python-mode

My Emacs default indent like this:

```
arr = {
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd'
    }
```

but I want it like this:

```
arr = {
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd'
}
```

How can I do ?

I use `python-mode`, Emacs version: 24.4.50.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Try hit `Tab` after you type `}`. Emacs will move `}` to the position you want.

Answer (score 1):

Shipped python.el as python-mode.el set symbol major-mode likewise onto python-mode - see <kbd>M-x describe-variable RET major-mode RET</kbd>.
From python-mode.el --it displays "Py" in modeline-- you could customize

`py-closing-list-dedents-bos` to `t`

Suffix "-bos" stands for beginning-of-statement, i.e. its indentation.